# not able to map all my product Attributes in commerce feeds

Tags: commerce, feeds

I'm using Feeds commerce to import all my product variation.

Here is my product variation definition

1. SKU
2. Price
3. Color
4. Size
5. Images

In the Feed Importer, I'm not able to map the Color,Size and Images. Anybody know why theses fields attribute is not showing up in the mapping dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: Did you select the correct product type in the feed importer admin page ???

Comment: Yes, and I have only one product type, which is called product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1031064 Try the dev version.

I had the same problem and after updating to the dev version all the missing fields were back. Seems there was a bug